# Can I get a list of Time Zones prior to API 24 in Android

Tags: android, time, timezone

I'm building a Time Zone converter app and want to get a list of all the time zones available so that I can present these in a recycler view and allow the user to choose from the time zone they want.  I then want to show the user the UTC time and the current and selected time zones.
The android.icu.util.TimeZone looks like it would work, but this is only introduced in API 24 and the old Time method is deprecated.
I've also looked at the Calendar and GregorianCalendar methods, but all are API 24 and above.
Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: you can still use [TimeZone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Comment: Why am I getting an error message that says: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): android.icu.util.TimeZone? Can I still use it? Won't it crash if a user is on a device earlier than API24?
     
Found the issue... instead of using android.icu.util package I needed to use the java.util package. –

Comment: Found the issue... instead of using android.icu.util package I needed to use the java.util package. – Thanks for the link @Blackbelt

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @WayneJohnson you should post this as an answer, not a comment, so people with a similar issue can find it

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue... instead of using android.icu.util package I needed to use the java.util package. – Thanks for the link @Blackbelt